# Passing a closure with child parameter type

Tags: swift

It is possible to pass a closure with a child type parameter to a function that accepts a closure with a parameter with a parent type in swift? Here's what I would like to pass my closure to. `MoveEvent` inherits from `Event`

```
func on(name:String,callback:(Event) -> ()){ ... }
```

And here's my call to this function:

```
symbol.on("move",{ (event:MoveEvent) ->() in
    ...
});
```

When I try this, xcode says I can't invoke it with those arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with generics:

```
class Event {}

class MoveEvent: Event {}

func on<T: Event>(name:String, callback:(T) -> ()) {}

on( "move", callback: { (event: MoveEvent) -> () in
    ...
});

on( "other", callback: { (event: Event) -> () in
    ...
});
```

But otherwise the signature of the closure you are defining when you call the `on(_:callback:)` function must match the signature of the closure used as the type of the argument—that is to say, you must use `Event` and not `MoveEvent` for the type of the `event` parameter.  If you are expecting a `MoveEvent` to be passed in, you must cast it to that type from `Event`.

```
symbol.on("move",{ (event:Event) ->() in
    if let moveEvent = event as? MoveEvent {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Casting is actually how I'm doing it now, I was just wondering if swift could somehow cast it for me without the extra syntax.  But I guess it makes sense it can't. I'll look at the generics though. Thanks.